# How to swipe through views in a containerView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

so I am new to using container views and I have taken some tutorials on how to put them into view controllers and connect them to the UIViewController you want to contain in storyboard.

I have an app I am building where the view controller in embed into a navigation controller. I have two buttons right under the nav bar that will show two different table Views.

I want to be able to either press the button to slide the table views in/out or swipe left/right to change between them.

My question is how can I bring in a new container view, I cant drag it onto the storyboard without it being placed into an already existing view controller and since I already have one I cant place it in there.

Am i going about this the wrong way. Is there a better solution without using container views?

Here is the process im looking for with images:

[image: first view]

[image: mid view - while swiping]

[image: final view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you want here is to be putting your two different table views inside a Page View Controller inside your navigation controller.

As for problems dragging onto the storyboard, it's easier to put things where you want in a nested layout by dragging them into the outline hierarchy on the left, which if you don't see it is revealed by the "Show Document Outline" button in the lower left corner.

Answer (score 0):

You can place as many UIContainerViews in a view as you'd like. You are simply embedding a view that will display some other viewController that is assigned on viewDidLoad of that container. Use prepareForSegue to capture the exact viewController. Dragging the container view onto your existing view is exactly how you do this and it's purpose.

Comment: So I can ctrl-drag a container view and connect it to both tableViewControllers and use prepare for segue to present which ever one I want? @DCGod

Comment: No, a container view is nothing more than a view that displays a UIViewController's view. The process involves loading a UIViewController via an embed segue (this only fires once on viewDidLoad) which is displayed in a container view. You drop a container view on any UIView and treat it like any other view. Once you have a reference to it (which you can get in the prepareForSegue function) you can access any of it's values. This makes designing complex views much cleaner. It's actually much simpler than most people think.